# Data from API call not going into console as requested

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to use an API that accesses various information about the stock market. I have copied their sample call just to see what data I get back and then I am trying to log the data into the console. This doesn't seem to work for some reason. The call is successful, as shown in the network tab, data is being retrieved but the console.log isn't printing it. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this? Here is the call I'm making.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Profile = () => {

  const loadProfile = async () => {
    await axios.get(
      'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token={hiddenforquestion}',
      {json: true},
      (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(body.url);
        console.log(body)
      }
    );
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadProfile}>See data</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: It looks like you require an API key to get the data. Look into their documentation

Comment: try `res = await axios.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token={hiddenforquestion}'); console.log(res)`

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your code like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Profile = () => {
    const loadProfile = async () => {
        await axios
            .get(
                `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news?category=general&token=${yourTokenVariable}`
            )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={loadProfile}>See data</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: I have an API key...i just hid in in the code i posted here. I'm getting a reply from the API, just not seeing it show up in the console tab, instead its in the network tab